# Convert array of values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => AS34
            [2014-12-10] => 32
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => AS34
            [2014-12-11] => 42
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => AS34
            [2014-12-12] => 40
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [code] => AS34
            [2014-12-15] => 44
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [code] => AH98
            [2014-12-10] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [code] => AT78
            [2014-12-12] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [code] => AL44
            [2014-12-10] => 23
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [code] => AL44
            [2014-12-11] => 27
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [code] => AL44
            [2014-12-13] => 25
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [code] => AL44
            [2014-12-15] => 26
        )
)
```

I am trying to turn it into an array that looks like this...

```
var $example_data = array(
            array(
                'ID'        => 1,
                'code'     => 'AS34',
                '09/12/14'    => '0',
                '10/12/14'    => '32',
                '11/12/14'    => '42',
                '12/12/14'    => '40',
                '13/12/14'    => '0',
                '14/12/14'    => '0',
                '15/12/14'    => '44',
            ),
            array(
                'ID'        => 2,
                'code'     => 'AH98',
                '09/12/14'    => '0',
                '10/12/14'    => '1',
                '11/12/14'    => '0',
                '12/12/14'    => '0',
                '13/12/14'    => '0',
                '14/12/14'    => '0',
                '15/12/14'    => '0',
            ),
            array(
                'ID'        => 3,
                'code'     => 'AT78',
                '09/12/14'    => '0',
                '10/12/14'    => '0',
                '11/12/14'    => '0',
                '12/12/14'    => '1',
                '13/12/14'    => '0',
                '14/12/14'    => '0',
                '15/12/14'    => '0',
            ),
            array(
                'ID'        => 4,
                'code'     => 'AL44',
                '09/12/14'    => '0',
                '10/12/14'    => '23',
                '11/12/14'    => '27',
                '12/12/14'    => '0',
                '13/12/14'    => '25',
                '14/12/14'    => '0',
                '15/12/14'    => '26',
            ),
        );
```

So basically it sets up an array for each 'code' and then the previous 7 days.  Can anybody point me in the direction of a similar example or some reading on the right method I should be looking at using?

Comment: So the `'code'` attribute is the unique identifier per array?

Comment: So, to make everything clear before moving forward with this: all `id`'s are the same `1`?

Comment: They are currently all set to 1, I can change this if it makes things easier?

Comment: just asking (because it really make things easier) why would you have a field with the name ID always as 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this:

```
$data = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "code" => "AS34",
            "2014-12-10" => 32
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "code" => "AS34",
            "2014-12-11" => 42
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "code" => "AS34",
            "2014-12-12" => 40
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "code" => "AS34",
            "2014-12-15" => 44
        ),

    4 => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "code" => "AH98",
            "2014-12-10" => 1
        ),

    5 => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "code" => "AT78",
            "2014-12-12" => 1
        ),

    6 => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "code" => "AL44",
            "2014-12-10" => 23
        ),

    7 => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "code" => "AL44",
            "2014-12-11" => 27
        ),

    8 => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "code" => "AL44",
            "2014-12-13" => 25
        ),

    9 => Array
        (
            "id" => 1,
            "code" => "AL44",
            "2014-12-15" => 26
        )
);

function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) { //taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4128377/4263082

    foreach ($haystack as $item) {

        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;
}

$codes = Array();
$counter = -1;

foreach($data as $key => $value) {

    if(!in_array_r($data[$key]["code"], $codes, true)) {

        $codes[++$counter] = Array();

        foreach($data[$key] as $subkey => $subvalue) {$codes[$counter][$subkey] = $subvalue;}

    }
    else{

        foreach($data[$key] as $subkey => $subvalue) {

            if($subkey != "code" && $subkey != "id") {$codes[$counter][$subkey] = $subvalue;}

        }

    }

}

print_r($codes);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => AS34
            [2014-12-10] => 32
            [2014-12-11] => 42
            [2014-12-12] => 40
            [2014-12-15] => 44
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => AH98
            [2014-12-10] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => AT78
            [2014-12-12] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => AL44
            [2014-12-10] => 23
            [2014-12-11] => 27
            [2014-12-13] => 25
            [2014-12-15] => 26
        )

)
```

Comment: I'm getting an  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() for $data

Comment: I tested that here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and the **OUTPUT** that I posted in the answer is taken from the result of that test in that site. Let me see if I typoed something while copy/pasting.

Comment: No, it's perfectly find. Do this: copy all the code in the first block of code (not the ouput code of course), enter this site: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ , paste the code there, and hit runcode. That's what I did.

Comment: But it doesnt work if you use my original data.  I think it is the formatting of the array?

Comment: I used the array that you have in the first block of code in your question. Of course, I made some changes to pass the parsing like removing `[]` wrapping keys with quotes, providing commas, etc. But the data is the same. You have to name that array `$data`.

Comment: Then I think I need to create a new stack question on how to format my array like yours!

Comment: Again: it is your array, I just provide it a name `$data` and fix the parsing errors. Plus, a different array shouldnt be a problem either as long as it is a 2d array.

Comment: If you need to parse the output of print_r - 
here is a solution for it here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218698/is-there-a-way-to-parse-the-output-of-print-r

see function print_r_reverse in the comments here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 1):

Something like (fixed):

```
$example_data = array();
foreach($data as $id => $row) {
    $code = $row['code'];
    unset($row['code']);

    $karr = array_keys($row);
    $date = current($karr);

    $example_data[$code]['ID'] = $id;
    $example_data[$code]['code'] = $code;
    $example_data[$code][$date] = $row[$date];
}
print_r($example_data);
```

[Test online](http://runnable.com/me/VJANE1r3BQlhR-bJ)

Comment: What does $array represent here?   Is this the original array?

Comment: I tested that approach here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it doesn't get the date keys just `code` and `id`. You may use that site to fix your function. It looks can be a good one.

Comment: Thanx @Varhaeren for suggestion. Dates are fixed now, and you can test it on Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working:

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

//source data from the question
$sourceArr = array(
  array('id'            => 1
        ,'code'         => 'AS34'
        ,'2014-12-10'   => '32'
  )
  ,array('id'           => 1
         ,'code'        => 'AS34'
         ,'2014-12-11'  => '42'
  )
  ,array('id'           => 1
         ,'code'        => 'AS34'
         ,'2014-12-12'  => '40'
  )
  ,array('id'           => 1
         ,'code'        => 'AS34'
         ,'2014-12-15'  => '44'
  )
  ,array('id'           => 1
         ,'code'        => 'AH98'
         ,'2014-12-10'  => '1'
  )
  ,array('id'           => 1
         ,'code'        => 'AT78'
         ,'2014-12-12'  => '1'
  )
  ,array('id'           => 1
         ,'code'        => 'AL44'
         ,'2014-12-10'  => '23'
  )
  ,array('id'           => 1
         ,'code'        => 'AL44'
         ,'2014-12-11'  => '27'
  )
  ,array('id'           => 1
         ,'code'        => 'AL44'
         ,'2014-12-13'  => '25'
  )
  ,array('id'           => 1
         ,'code'        => 'AL44'
         ,'2014-12-15'  => '26'
  )
);

foreach($sourceArr as $k => $v)
{
  //get dates for last seven days
  $d0 = date('Y-m-d',time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 0);
  $d1 = date('Y-m-d',time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 1);
  $d2 = date('Y-m-d',time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 2);
  $d3 = date('Y-m-d',time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 3);
  $d4 = date('Y-m-d',time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 4);
  $d5 = date('Y-m-d',time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 5);
  $d6 = date('Y-m-d',time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 6);

  //if we have a valid element - then save it in temp array
  if(array_key_exists($d0,$v)){ $tmpArr[$v['code']][$d0] = "'$v[$d0]'"; }
  if(array_key_exists($d1,$v)){ $tmpArr[$v['code']][$d1] = "'$v[$d1]'"; }
  if(array_key_exists($d2,$v)){ $tmpArr[$v['code']][$d2] = "'$v[$d2]'"; }
  if(array_key_exists($d3,$v)){ $tmpArr[$v['code']][$d3] = "'$v[$d3]'"; }
  if(array_key_exists($d4,$v)){ $tmpArr[$v['code']][$d4] = "'$v[$d4]'"; }
  if(array_key_exists($d5,$v)){ $tmpArr[$v['code']][$d5] = "'$v[$d5]'"; }
  if(array_key_exists($d6,$v)){ $tmpArr[$v['code']][$d6] = "'$v[$d6]'"; }

}

//create the result array
$cnt = 0;
foreach($tmpArr as $k => $v)
{
  $resultArr[$cnt]['ID'] = $cnt;
  $resultArr[$cnt]['code'] = "'$k'";
  asort($v);
  foreach($v as $k2 => $v2)
  {
    $resultArr[$cnt][$k2] = $v2;
  }
  $cnt++;
}

//output
echo "Old array: ".print_r($sourceArr,1);
echo "New array: ".print_r($resultArr,1);

?>
```