# Recreate original PHP array from print_r output

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, output

Let's say I have this output from some source where I don't have access to the original PHP created array:

```
Array
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [name] => Arduino Nano Version 3.0 mit ATMEGA328P
            [id] => 10005
        )

    [listings] => Array
        (
            [category] => 
            [title] => This is the first line
This is the second line
            [subtitle] => This is the first subtitle
This is the second subtitle
            [price] => 24.95
            [quantity] => 
            [stock] => 
            [shipping_method] => Slow and cheap
            [condition] => New
            [defects] => 
        )

    [table_count] => 2
    [tables] => Array
        (
            [0] => products
            [1] => listings
        )

)
```

Now I would like to input that data and have an algorithm recreate the original array that it was printing so I can then use it for my own application.

Currently I am thinking about a `sub_str()` and regex statements that pull data and place it appropriately. Before I head further, is there a simpler way, via already written code or php plugins that do this for me already out there?

IT MUST WORK FOR MULTIDEMNSIONAL ARRAY - so this post does not work and it even references the correct function to use:
[How create an array from the output of an array printed with print_r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/how-create-an-array-from-the-output-of-an-array-printed-with-print-r)

Comment: show what you've tried...

Comment: Currently i am thinking about a sub_str() and regex statements that pull data and place it appropriately. Before i head further, is there a simpler way, via already written code or php plugins that do this for me already out there?

Comment: this is what [var_export](http://www.php.net/var_export) is for, instead of print_r.

Comment: Also, check the user comments on php.net for [print_r](http://www.php.net/print_r). There are a couple reverse functions that have already been written.

Comment: You can write some basic parser for it, but as values aren't delimited, you may end up with a different array then the original, the `print_r` output was never meant to be read back in. (for instance, when `=> Array(` occurs in a value itself. Rare perhaps, but a consideration.

Comment: I've used this library with perfect results: https://github.com/simivar/reverse-print-r

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
function print_r_reverse($in) {
    $lines = explode("\n", trim($in));
    if (trim($lines[0]) != 'Array') {
        // bottomed out to something that isn't an array
        return $in;
    } else {
        // this is an array, lets parse it
        if (preg_match("/(\s{5,})\(/", $lines[1], $match)) {
            // this is a tested array/recursive call to this function
            // take a set of spaces off the beginning
            $spaces = $match[1];
            $spaces_length = strlen($spaces);
            $lines_total = count($lines);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $lines_total; $i++) {
                if (substr($lines[$i], 0, $spaces_length) == $spaces) {
                    $lines[$i] = substr($lines[$i], $spaces_length);
                }
            }
        }
        array_shift($lines); // Array
        array_shift($lines); // (
        array_pop($lines); // )
        $in = implode("\n", $lines);
        // make sure we only match stuff with 4 preceding spaces (stuff for this array and not a nested one)
        preg_match_all("/^\s{4}\[(.+?)\] \=\> /m", $in, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $pos = array();
        $previous_key = '';
        $in_length = strlen($in);
        // store the following in $pos:
        // array with key = key of the parsed array's item
        // value = array(start position in $in, $end position in $in)
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $key = $match[1][0];
            $start = $match[0][1] + strlen($match[0][0]);
            $pos[$key] = array($start, $in_length);
            if ($previous_key != '') $pos[$previous_key][1] = $match[0][1] - 1;
            $previous_key = $key;
        }
        $ret = array();
        foreach ($pos as $key => $where) {
            // recursively see if the parsed out value is an array too
            $ret[$key] = print_r_reverse(substr($in, $where[0], $where[1] - $where[0]));
        }
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

not my code, found here in the comments: [print_r](https://www.php.net/print_r)
'Matt' is the owner

Comment: Matt's function has been forked [here](https://gist.github.com/simivar/037b13a9bbd53ae5a092d8f6d9828bc3).

Comment: This [reverse print_r composer library with type-casting](https://github.com/simivar/reverse-print-r) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I also worked out a solution for your problem because it is a very useful tool to recreate issues here on Stack Overflow. My source is located here: https://github.com/etalon/aprp

I did it a bit different: In your string you don't need line-breaks, so I walk through the chars. One disatvantage: If there are brackets or parenthesis in your array-values it won't work.