# Returning an Array from a file

Tags: php, arrays, file

I've outputted my array to file using the `print_r($myArray, true)` method, but am having trouble re-importing it as an array.

I keep returning a string with the array, not the array itself. I've tried a few different combinations including print_r and serialize, but can't seem to get it right. What am I missing?

Here's what I have:

```
$myArray = print_r(file_get_contents($logFile), true);
```

for reference the log file content looks like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => blah
            [1] => blah
        )
...
```

Thanks

---

EDIT: Solution -  Here is what I came up with:

I changed the file contents to include php tags and declared the array there using var_export instead of print_r.

Here is what I used as my content string when writing to file:

```
<?php $myArray = '.var_export($myArray, true).'; ?'.'>
```

From there it was a simple include to get the array back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/create-array-printed-with-print-r The selected answer contains quite a nice function that could help you out!

Comment: @AdiBradfield thanks for that. I found another workaround that I think is a little cleaner.

Comment: Would you mind posting it? I'm intrigued!

Comment: @AdiBradfield I basically just did `fwrite($logFile, '<?php $myArray = '.var_export($myArray, true).'; ?'.'>')` and created a .php file with the array declared. I then just included it in the original.

Comment: Hmm that is a lot cleaner and no more hacky than that function! Good thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just store the array as ... an array, like so:

```
file_put_contents('myfile.txt', '<?php return ' . var_export($array, true) . '; ?>');
```

Then, to read:

```
$array = include 'myfile.txt';
```

See also: [`var_export()`](http://php.net/var_export)

Comment: Thanks - were were you an hour ago. :)

Comment: @John somewhere else I guess? :)