# PHP, file_get_contents, for loop, str_replace

Tags: php

I am quite new with PHP and I am trying to read something form an API.
At the moment I use

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.site.com');
echo $homepage
```

This returns something which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => myname
        [user_id] => 31232
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => anothername
        [user_id] => 23534
    )
)
```

So here is what I want: I only want to read the *[name] => x* and leave the rest, so I tried a for loop within str_replace, but all I got were errors.

I hope someone is able to help me

Edit:
I just saw I could set is as a json text too, it returns something like

```
[{"name":"myname","user_id":"31232"},{"name":"anothername","user_id":"23534"}]
```

Edit2: Thank you Tuga, that was exactly what I was searching for :) I can't upvote, since my reputaion is below 15, is there another way for me to show your answer helped?

Comment: show us this last code, what do you mean with read?

Comment: an api returning a raw php array, not xml or /??

Comment: So you are saying the contents of the URL are a PHP var_dump?  Otherwise just running `echo $homepage` would not produce that sort of variable dump format.  Are you not showing something?  If you are working with some sort of API, then you should be able to get the data in some kind of structured format (XML, JSON, or some other serialized format). At that point you would just take the structured data and work with it in PHP rather than trying to parse values out of it as a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create array printed with print\_r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/create-array-printed-with-print-r)

Comment: Why are you using `str_replace`?  What are you trying to do with that?  Does `echo $homepage;` *really* give you that *exact* output?  Or are you parsing it in some way before?  What is the *exact* output the page is giving you and what *exactly* so you want to do with it.

Comment: The API is probably giving you back a JSON string which can be parsed into an array that looks like that.  Try something like: `$data = json_decode($homepage, TRUE);  foreach($data as $x){ echo $x['name']; }`

Comment: You should past the code exactly as you see it, you may also post the url.

Answer (score 0):

`$array = json_decode($homepage);` will return an array, then you can loop the array containing objects and use 'name' attribute :

`foreach ($array as $obj) echo $obj->name;`