# In PHP, how can I convert an Array (dictionary) inside String variable to Array structure?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I was looking for in Stack some solution to convert a string variable to an Array. The String variable contents this:

```
$myvar = 'array("a" => array("b1" => 1, "b2" => "something"), "c" => array("d1" => 1))';
```

I want to convert as:

```
$myarray = array(
     "a" => array (   
         "b1" => 1, 
         "b2" => "something"
     ),
     "c" => array("d1" => 1)      
);
```

I was using `json_decode` after to convert my huge string to json, I used implode too ...

Using eval, I recieve next error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in tabletocreate.php(51) : eval()'d code on line 1`

I used print_r($myvar);

The idea it is I have an model inside a file model.php it is only a dictionary, I read this file inside a string and after to convert again an array, I do it because I need to generate a new database from this data, and I have the model for each catalog I need products, offer, ... obiously each model will be different but with the same structure of array, I wrote in the example

**SOLUTION**

[faintsignal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3303195/faintsignal) resolved the solution in my case: `eval("\$myarray = " . $myvar . ';');`

Comment: Yes, `json_decode` is the way, but you don't say what happened when you tried it.

Comment: If you are in control over how the array is saved / persisted, you should have a look at the [serialize()](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions.

Comment: Your first example is not a valid PHP string

Comment: sorry true Utkanos, it returns me Array only with one element whcih is the string

Comment: from where you are getting the string `$myvar`, can you show more details of your `PHP` code

Comment: I forgot the ', I changed it sorry

Comment: you should take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/create-array-printed-with-print-r

Comment: Maybe you could use `eval`(it is deprecated).

Comment: @GuyT Why do you say is `eval` deprecated?

Comment: @faintsignal My bad, it isn't deprecated. In javascript it is(but this is PHP). But, be careful by using it with external resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval()` will accomplish what you need, but as another poster here advided in his answer, you must use this function with great caution.

```
$myvar = 'array("a" => array("b1" => 1, "b2" => "something"), "c" => array("d1" => 1))';
eval("\$myarray = " . $myvar . ';');
var_dump($myarray);
```

outputs

```
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["b1"]=>
    int(1)
    ["b2"]=>
    string(9) "something"
  }
  ["c"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["d1"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Someone commented that `eval` is deprecated but I cannot find any info to support this. However, its use is *discouraged*, so you might consider it as a last resort when existing PHP functionality will not accomplish your task.

Comment: It worked in my PHP server. Thanks faintsignal. I lost one day to try to find a solution but It is something simple I dont understand why eval is deprecated, I look info for you commented and I didnt' find too. ANYWAY THANKS

Comment: I dont have reputation to do this, sorry I would love to do it

Comment: Aziz what I did is set the answer in my question, is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Use eval() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

`$myarray = eval($myvar)`

But don't do this if you're getting the $myvar from outside your script. Also, there are much better methods to serialize and unserialize data in PHP. For instance see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

If you're reading a .php file directly you have to deal with `<?php` and `?>`. You can pre-parse the file before passing it to `eval()`. If your file is as simple as:

`<?php (php_declarations_and_stuff ?>`

You can just remove `<?php` and `?>`, and the `eval()` the file.

Another option may be just use `include` against the file. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php. In this case `include` will eval the file in the global scope. Also see that if your included file uses `return`, you can just retrieve this value directly (See Example #5 in the include reference):

return.php
`<?php return 'Ok'; ?>`

myfile.php
`$val = include('return.php');
print $val;`

Will print "Ok".

Comment: $myvar = 'array("a")'; 
print_r(eval($myvar)); tried it in my code and it is not working, give me an error eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Could you post the error? Also, what exactly are you trying to do? Because if you're trying to just define an array is much simpler than that.