# string to array conversion using php

Tags: php, arrays, string, type-conversion

I have a string like following...

```
Array ([product_name] => this is a product [product_desc] => some descripyion [cat_id] => 3)
```

This is looking like as an array but this is a string. If I use echo then it prints the same result.

```
$someVariable = "Array ([product_name] => this is a product [product_desc] => some descripyion [cat_id] => 3)";

echo $someVariable;
```

Result:

```
Array ([product_name] => this is a product [product_desc] => some descripyion [cat_id] => 3)
```

I need it to convert to an array so that I can do the following..

```
echo $someVariable['product_name'];
```

and get the following result

```
this is a product
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: This is very very hard, if not impossible. Why do you have "arrays" in this format to begin with? You should use a better serialisation format than `var_dump`.

Comment: Agree with @deceze, please explain why you have an array in string format?

Comment: using explode function you can do this

Comment: what is the need of putting this printed format of array in string. what you are doing actully?

Comment: I am passing the values of a form to the several steps of pages.here is the example to make it more clear..I have a form..when I click submit button it shows the preview using the values of the form submitted as post method and then I set the values to a hidden form element to the preview page and again after clicking the submit button I take the values to the next page..But when I set the values of the first form to a form element it converts to the string..and when I click submit button I get the values but at the string format..

Comment: please first explain how you got an array in string format?

Comment: The format of string is quite strange, but if you really need to convert it to real array you should remove "Array ([", then use explode by "[" and then each element explode by "] =>"

Comment: If there is no easy solution then I have do this in a different way..

Comment: you can use the hidden values right

Comment: after submitting from preview page where should it go?

Comment: after submitting from preview page I will insert the data to the database

Comment: then you can use the hidden values

Comment: you have to submit the for use the hidden id for inserting

Comment: somebody already answered something like this, cant find it though

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/create-array-printed-with-print-r

Comment: What about if you run serialize() on the array before you submit the form and then convert it back into an array with unserialize().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`serialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) the data:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data" valaue='<?php print_r(serialize($yourData));?>'>
```

And then [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize):

```
<?php 
    $youralldata = unserialize($_POST['data']);
    print_r($youralldata);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$someVariable = "Array ([product_name] => this is a product [product_desc] => some descripyion [cat_id] => 3)";

preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $someVariable, $keys);
preg_match_all('/=> (.*?) ?[\[|\)]/', $someVariable, $values);

$someVariable = array_combine($keys[1], $values[1]);
```

This converts the string back into an array.

Comment: Good point. You would have to validate your input. It's definitely better to avoid having to do this.

Comment: Yes, avoiding this whole situation is the only reasonable answer. `var_dump` is not suitable to serialise arbitrary values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function stringToArray($string){
    $pattern = '/\[(.*?)\]|=>\s+[\w\s\d]+/';
    preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);
    $result = array();
    foreach($matches[0] as $i => $match){
        if($i%2 == 0){
                    $key = trim(str_ireplace(array("[","]"),"",$match));
            $value = trim(str_ireplace(array("=>"),"",$matches[0][$i+1]));
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$someVariable =   "Array ([product_name] => this is a product [product_desc] => some descripyion [cat_id] => 3)";

$someVariable = stringToArray($someVariable);

echo $someVariable['product_name'];
```