# How can i convert an array to proper format in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which i getting from an api, but its format is not correct.

### Response Array

```
Array
(
    [route] => checkout/success
    [utf8] => ✓
    [req_bill_to_address_country] => AE
    [auth_avs_code] => 1

)
```

I'm getting this array through `$_Request`

```
print_r($_Request);
```

I want to convert it in this format.

```
Array
(
    'route' => 'checkout/success',
    'utf8' => '✓',
    'req_bill_to_address_country' => 'AE',
    'auth_avs_code' => 1

)
```

So how can i do this, I have tried with `explode()` function but its not converting properly.

Comment: Are you not able to access that response array

Comment: @Vicky What do you means? Well if you asking about getting response then yes i'm getting response from API

Comment: **Why** do you want to convert it?

Comment: @u_mulder because i want to save it in database as key values

Comment: All that you have now is just a **visual representation** of array. It doesn't affect array itself. Do what you need with it.

Comment: @u_mulder I want to execute foreach loop on it but does not working. `foreach($_Request as $key => $val)`

Comment: Please, describe real problem what you have with this array and show all **relevant** code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99107/discussion-between-adnan-khalid-and-u-mulder).

Comment: @u_mulder I already described in the question, i want to execute foreach loop on the array but it does not working properly. You can check first array which i mention in my question

Comment: Ok. then wait for someone who can imagine what you `foreach` does and how exactly it should work.

Comment: @u_mulder just check first array you will understand the problem, you can see in first array there is not single quote and comma, however as you know these are important for an key value array

Comment: both of the array are identical..imo

Comment: You can check the following answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/how-create-an-array-from-the-output-of-an-array-printed-with-print-r

Comment: If you believe that visual representation of array matters, then I have some bad news for you - http://pastebin.com/jcQ4m8PR

Comment: maybe instead of `print_r`, try `var_export`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
$str = "Array
(
    [route] => checkout/success
    [utf8] => ✓
    [req_bill_to_address_country] => AE
    [auth_avs_code] => 1

)";

$str = str_replace(["    ",')','(','Array'],"",$str);
$array = explode("\n",$str);


$res = [];
foreach($array as $row){
    if(!empty($row)){
        $temp = explode(" => ",$row,2);
        $res[str_replace(["[","]"],"",$temp[0])] = $temp[1];
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

The $res variable is your standard array and you can use this in your code