# Extract data from array in strange order

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to organize a array I have into a string.

I have this array:

```
array(27) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tp__string"]=>
    string(3) "AA,"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(16) "515.771314999996"
    ["count"]=>
    int(47)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tp__string"]=>
    string(3) "BB,"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(11) "2718.860891"
    ["count"]=>
    int(281)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tp__string"]=>
    string(3) "CC,"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(16) "619.105467999996"
    ["count"]=>
    int(44)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tp__string"]=>
    string(3) "DD,"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(16) "2088.84192300001"
    ["count"]=>
    int(131)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tp__string"]=>
    string(3) "EE,"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(12) "12124.710324"
    ["count"]=>
    int(955)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tp__string"]=>
    string(3) "BB,"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(10) "1543.73578"
    ["count"]=>
    int(164)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tp__string"]=>
    string(3) "CC,"
    ["cost"]=>
    string(16) "319.932651999999"
    ["count"]=>
    int(26)
  }
```

This is how i need to have data organized

[image]

So I have to create some string like: `echo '515.771314999996', '47', 'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL';` - example of the second line.

The Keys can change, and also the number of columns and rows.
What is the easiest and fastest way to extract the data?

---

**EDIT**

To create first line I have this:

```
function array_flatten($array) {
    $return = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)){ $return = array_merge($return, array_flatten($value));}
        else {$return[$key] = $value;}
    }
    return $return;
}

function unset_num_keys($array){
    $array_out = array();
    foreach($array AS $k => $v)
    {
        if(is_array($v))                           
        {
            $array_out[$k] = unset_num_keys($v);    
        }
        elseif(!is_numeric($k))
        {
            $array_out[$k] = $v;                    
        }
    }
    return $array_out;
}


$arr = (unset_num_keys($aaa));

$tmp = array();
foreach($arr as $x){
    array_push($tmp, (array_keys($x)));
}

$titles = (array_unique(array_flatten($tmp)));

$first_value = reset($titles);
$firstColum = array();
foreach($titles as $title){
    foreach($arr as $a){
      array_push($firstColum, $a[$first_value]);
    }
}


$first_line = "['x', ";
end($arr);
$total = key($arr);

$i = 0;


$firlsColum_clean= (array_unique(array_flatten($firstColum)));

foreach ($firlsColum_clean as $first) {
    $new = str_replace(',', '', $first);
    if ($i == $total) {
        $first_line .= $new;
    } else {
        $first_line .= $new . ', ';
    }
    $i += 1;
}
$first_line .= "],";
```

But I'm having troubles understanding the logic of the next lines.

Comment: If you need help for someone, before that you must put the piece of code you tried.

Comment: You said that the number of columns may change, what is the range of `tp__string` values ?

Comment: @Heah can be from 1 to 300 , i never know how many

Comment: I'm not talking about rows but columns like `AA` or `EE` as show in your example of data output

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach and implode to parse the array then write code to organize the result string

Answer (score 0):

[[How create an array from the output of an array printed with print_r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/how-create-an-array-from-the-output-of-an-array-printed-with-print-r][1])
check the link, you will find your solution, here i found the question similar to yours..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for above solution

```
$array1=array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
     //put the value into X field
     echo $value['cost'];
     if(in-array($value['tp_string'],$array1))
     {
        //put the value of tp_strings to corrosponding column and all other put null value
        echo  $value['tp_strings'];
     }
     else
     {
          array_push($value['tp_string'],$array1);
          //create new coloumn and put value into new column and all other put null value
          echo $value['tp_strings'];
      }


}
```

Comment: So create the aaray of tp_strings check first this tp_strings present in array if present go for inserting value into column otherwise insert this tp_strings to array and put new columns add this new tp_strings to new columns..Check it every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar = array() // your data here
$result = array() // this is what we will use later
$head = array() // this is your column headers

// make your data make sense
foreach($ar as $item) {
  $result[$item['cost']][$item['tp_string']]=$item['count'];
  if(!in_array($item['tp_string'], $head)) $head[] = $item['tp_string'];
}

// sort the columns
sort($head);

// print your headers
print 'X';
foreach($head as $col) print ",{$col}";

// print your data
foreach($result as $cost=>$data) {
  print PHP_EOL;
  print $cost;

  // print the row data
  foreach($head as $col) {
    print ',' . (isset($data[$col])) ? $data[$col] : "NULL");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shaun. There is a problem. I don't know name of keys. Also it display a lot of Notice: Undefined index:

Comment: Also it doesnt print NULL

Comment: I wrote the code on my phone so you may have to debug a little. NULL should be in single quotes instead of double quotes. :-) I also forgot a couple of semicolons. And I'm not sure how I can help if you don't know the keys. You don't know that each array has a cost, a tp_string, and a count? Are those they keys you are don't know? If that's the case, I'm not sure how I can help.

Comment: i debug it. only one problem now, cost,tp_string may change , need to figure it out how to do it