# convert print_r array of objects string to json in php

Tags: php

One of my team member has saved the object in Mysql database. I need to extract the object properties values. When I am trying to fetch it from Mysql using PHP, I am getting this as string. And no luck of accessing the property directly except an idea of using PHP `substr()` function.

Is there any option to convert the below string saved in database to object again so that I can access the property of it.

```
stdClass Object
(
[status] => 0
[environment] => Sandbox
[receipt] => stdClass Object
    (
        [quantity] => 1
        [expires_date] => 2017-04-18 08:56:57 Etc/GMT
        [is_trial_period] => false
        [purchase_date] => 2017-04-18 08:51:57 Etc/GMT
        [product_id] => com.1monthAuto.baseball
        [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2017-04-18 01:51:58 America/Los_Angeles
        [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1492505518000
        [web_order_line_item_id] => 1000000034854560
        [original_purchase_date] => 2017-04-18 08:51:58 Etc/GMT
    )

[latest_receipt] => MIIT6wYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIT3DCCE9gC
)
```

Comment: which property you want to access?

Comment: Storing objects in databases sounds like a terrible designpattern to me, because it will lead to issues like this.

Comment: I want to access `latest_receipt`.

Comment: Are you sure that's literally the string? So somebody is storing output from `print_r` in the database? That's awful. Anyway.. time for you to learn how to write a parser, and maybe some regex. I don't think anyone will straight up write it for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/how-create-an-array-from-the-output-of-an-array-printed-with-print-r

Comment: Is there any better idea to access latest_receipt. As the data is big, This would not be feasible to change the store logic right now.

Comment: did you try `unserialize($field_from_db)` ?

Comment: Yes I tried unserialize, but the literal text is saved as shown above. So no luck yet.

Comment: `/\[latest_receipt\] => ([^\s]+)/`

Comment: [Garbage in, garbage out.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) ;-) You should `json_encode` the data before saving or something like this. Or write a parser and get potentially inconsistent results.

Comment: https://blog.nixarsoft.com/2021/04/16/convert-print_r-result-to-json/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this hope this will help you out.

**Regex:** `/latest_receipt\]\s*=>\s*\K[^\s\)]+/`

`latest_receipt\]\s*=>\s*` this will match latest_receipt]spaces=>spaces

`\K` will reset previous match

`[^\s\)]+` this will match all except space(`\s`) and `)`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/779732)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='stdClass Object
(
[status] => 0
[environment] => Sandbox
[receipt] => stdClass Object
    (
        [quantity] => 1
        [expires_date] => 2017-04-18 08:56:57 Etc/GMT
        [is_trial_period] => false
        [purchase_date] => 2017-04-18 08:51:57 Etc/GMT
        [product_id] => com.1monthAuto.baseball
        [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2017-04-18 01:51:58 America/Los_Angeles
        [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1492505518000
        [web_order_line_item_id] => 1000000034854560
        [original_purchase_date] => 2017-04-18 08:51:58 Etc/GMT
    )

[latest_receipt] => MIIT6wYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIT3DCCE9gC
)';
preg_match("/latest_receipt\]\s*=>\s*\K[^\s\)]+/", $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Solution 2:**  [or you can Try this library](https://github.com/Sahil-Gulati/PSTJ)
//this solution will convert `print_r` to `json`, and work surely.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php)(`Copy paste below code and check`)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
/**
 * @author Sahil Gulati <sahil.gulati1991@outlook.com> 
 */
echo printr_source_to_json(
        print_r(
                array("Name"=>"Sahil Gulati",
                      "Education"=>array(
                          "From"=>array(
                              "DU"=>array(
                                  "Course"=>"B.Sc. (Hons.) Computer Science.")
                              )
                          )
                    )
                , true
                )
        );
/**
 * This function will convert output string of `print_r($array)` to `json string`
 * @note Exceptions are always there i tried myself best to get it done. Here $array can be array of arrays or arrays of objects or both
 * @param String $string This will contain the output of `print_r($array)` (which user will get from ctrl+u of browser),
 * @return String
 */
function printr_source_to_json($string)
{
    /**
     *replacing `stdClass Objects (` to  `{`
     */
    $string = preg_replace("/stdClass Object\s*\(/s", '{  ', $string);

    /**
     *replacing `Array (` to  `{`
     */
    $string = preg_replace("/Array\s*\(/s", '{  ', $string);
    /**
     *replacing `)\n` to  `},\n`
     * @note This might append , at the last of string as well 
     * which we will trim later on.
     */
    $string = preg_replace("/\)\n/", "},\n", $string);

    /**
     *replacing `)` to  `}` at the last of string
     */
    $string = preg_replace("/\)$/", '}', $string);
    /**
     *replacing `[ somevalue ]` to "somevalue"
     */
    $string = preg_replace("/\[\s*([^\s\]]+)\s*\](?=\s*\=>)/", '"\1" ', $string);
    /**
     * replacing `=> {`  to `: {`
     */
    $string = preg_replace("/=>\s*{/", ': {', $string);
    /**
     * replacing empty last values of array special case `=> \n }` to : "" \n
     */
    $string = preg_replace("/=>\s*[\n\s]*\}/s", ":\"\"\n}", $string);

    /**
     * replacing `=> somevalue`  to `: "somevalue",` 
     */
    $string = preg_replace("/=>\s*([^\n\"]*)/", ':"\1",', $string);
    /**
     * replacing last mistakes `, }` to `}` 
     */
    $string = preg_replace("/,\s*}/s", '}', $string);
    /**
     * replacing `} ,` at the end to `}`
     */
    return $string = preg_replace("/}\s*,$/s", '}', $string);
}
```

Comment: +1 This seems a better idea to extract the value. Is there any option available to make this string to object so that I can extract other property values as well?

Comment: @ArunJain I created a new solution which i am going to post hope it will help you out

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex and str_replace to have the latest_receipt content as a string :

```
$dictionary="stdClass Object
    (
    [status] => 0
    [environment] => Sandbox
    [receipt] => stdClass Object
        (
            [quantity] => 1
            [expires_date] => 2017-04-18 08:56:57 Etc/GMT
            [is_trial_period] => false
            [purchase_date] => 2017-04-18 08:51:57 Etc/GMT
            [product_id] => com.1monthAuto.baseball
            [original_purchase_date_pst] => 2017-04-18 01:51:58 America/Los_Angeles
            [original_purchase_date_ms] => 1492505518000
            [web_order_line_item_id] => 1000000034854560
            original_purchase_date] => 2017-04-18 08:51:58 Etc/GMT
        )

    [latest_receipt] => MIIT6wYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIT3DCCE9gC
    )";
preg_match('/.*\[latest_receipt\].*$/m', $dictionary, $matches);
$receipt = str_replace('[latest_receipt] => ', '', $matches[0]);
echo $receipt;
```

You can make it a function and replace latest_receipt with a variable to extract your other data.

But you should really think about storing it as a json object or to create new columns to store this data..