# convert array text file into array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have text file of array values 
for example

```
[26-11-2018 04:07:26]:     Array
(
    [0] => api.flights_published_search
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ticket_type] => single
                    [departure_airport_id] => THR
                    [arrival_airport_id] => MHD
                    [departure_date] => 21/12/2018
                    [direct_flight_only] => 0
                    [adults] => 1
                    [children] => 1
                    [child_ages] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 11
                        )

                    [infants] => 1
                    [cabin_class] => Y
                )

        )

)

[26-11-2018 04:07:27]:     Array
(
    [status] => 1
    [pscId] => 0
    [localInventory] => Array
        (
            [cal] => 0
            [resp] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [status] => 
            [error] => Error Code: 3037, Error: No availability on chosen flights.
        )

)
```

I want to convert into as it is in array through php coding . so can anyone suggegst best way to convert this text to php array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How create an array from the output of an array printed with print\_r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025909/how-create-an-array-from-the-output-of-an-array-printed-with-print-r)

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#93529

Comment: ^ The accepted answer doesn't really work, but check [the answer by Adrian Cid Almaguer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28687593/2453432)

Comment: Well, if you could access the PHP array, then you can simply serialize and unserialize it.

Comment: these array values are in log text file. so need to convert into array as it

Comment: The log file is generated by an external system. It logs all the requests and responses from an API system

Unfortunately the way it is generated makes it difficult to convert as the structure is not a valid array.